# Same class in different product flavour give error of Duplicate class found

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

In my code , i need to have two product flavors in which one flavor (main) have min api level 15 and one flavor (mainv9) have min api level 9 . In main flavor , i need to include a library that doesn't provide support flavor mainv9 .

so i replicated my files .java in the both product flavor folder like this

src\main\java\com\util\Utility.java
src\main\google-services.json

src\mainv9\java\com\util\Utility.java
src\mainv9\google-services.json

In flavor main in the Utility class i have the code related to the external library , that is supported only for min api level 15

In flavor mainv9 in the Utility class i have the code without that external library calls part.

My build.gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
    mainv9
            {
                java.srcDirs = [ 'src/mainv9/java']
            }
}


productFlavors {
    defaultFlavor {
        applicationId 'com.app'
        applicationIdSuffix ".default"
        versionNameSuffix "-default"
        minSdkVersion 15
        signingConfig signingConfigs.APPkey
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    mainv9 {
        applicationId 'com.app'
        applicationIdSuffix ".mainv9"
        versionNameSuffix "-mainv9"
        minSdkVersion 9
        signingConfig signingConfigs.APPkey
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
//noinspection GroovyMissingReturnStatement
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    defaultFlavorCompile 'io.lib.android:lib-sdk-base:3+'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But when i try to build the mainv9 flavor then i get this error that duplicate class found in the file  Utility.java .

Please help me with this.

Comment: Yes for this solution you have to add your java file to all the falvours and you have to remove it from main falvour. It was work for me.

Comment: yes im agree with @RujulGandhi

Comment: Can you please help with rectified gradle?

Comment: Can we keep the same google-services.json file for every flavor. or we need to keep seperate files

Comment: @Rujul Gnadhi- thanks a lot . I was able to perform the same task. but there is a small problem that the google-services.json file , cannot be same for all the flavors and it needs to be replicated fir each flavor but the package name needs to have some kind of changes . Can you please help me with this as the google login is not working  any mor e